pregunta sobre funciones JavaScript
Un ejercicio dice que

Una empresa tiene guardado un registro con sus ingresos durante el año
2022. Los datos los tiene guardados en una tabla como la siguiente:

let ingresos = [7965,8714,8446,2612,7241,2872,2008,4857,4896,4986,5746,6676,5285,4427,5843,8285,8601,5245,7582,9616,3245,9253,6749,2109,9709,6883,4239,3458,1215,9451,3573,7977,5037,7242,7380,3856,3444,5911,5452,9878,5781,2218,7557,5580,6199,6821,2204,2305,8746,7637,8682,4409,4749];
let valorDado = 5000

Esta empresa tiene un equipo de comerciales. Los datos sobre los ingresos mensuales generados por cada comercial están guardados en una tabla de objetos (como la que aparece en la variable de ejemplo comer).
Cada elemento de la tabla es un objeto con dos campos: el nombre del comercial y una tabla con la facturación de los doce meses del año de ese comercial.
Tengo que hacer una función que, recibido como parámetro la tabla de objetos, nos retorne el nombre del comercial que más ha facturado en todo el año.
Nota: dan por supuesto no hay dos comerciales que hayan facturado lo mismo.
// Esta variable es un ejemplo. La función debe estar hecha pensando en que
// el número de comerciales puede variar.
let comer = [ {nom:"Daniel",fact:[6899,2713,6827,5805,3058,3679,4094,7581,5867,6901,5116,2392]}, {nom:"Raquel",fact:[6747,5485,7431,2667,2431,3900,7222,7601,5109,6556,6211,7087]}, {nom:"Eva",fact:[2831,2645,2242,5586,3124,7396,5556,3268,3186,6632,5319,2263]}, {nom:"Víctor",fact:[4758,6212,7835,6240,6513,6639,4246,3244,5914,3338,2415,5240]}, ];

Ayuda: podría ir bien crear una tabla donde guardar la suma de los ingresos mensuales de cada comercial.
En mi código he puesto


function comercial(tIngr){
 
    let arrayWithTotals = [];
    for (let comercial of objeto){
        let subtotal=0;
        for (let fact of comercial.fact){
           subtotal += parseInt(fact);
        }
        arrayWithTotals.push({nom: comercial.nom, total: subtotal});
    }
    return arrayWithTotals;
}
console.log(sumarIngresos(comer)));



Me dice que 'objeto' no está definido y da error de compilación y no se puede ejecutar.
No tengo que poner variables ni console.log;  por eso los he quitado.
console.log(maximo(sumarIngresos(comer)));

lo pongo para depurar aquí.
¿Me podéis ayudar, por favor? Gracias

Pulsa en [edit] y pon en el título el error específico que estás teniendo. Hazlo también en el cuerpo de la pregunta: te da error, ¿cuál error? ¿En qué momento da error?

ME sobra una llavecita de cierre al principio.. y en lo que entregas no podras poner ni variables ni console.log, pero si lo podes usar para depurar antes de entregar...

es mas.. ahora que lo edite... hay 2 returns??? hay una variable que se llama igual que la funcion???

el error es claro.. maximo no esta definido.. que es maximo?

que es comer? para que se usa el parametro en la funcion?

@puregirl Tienes preguntas anteriores sin completar, y has traido nuevamente el mismo problema inicial a la pregunta. Anteriormente ya te mostré como retornar los valores de un listado, y con data específica también. Por que ahora hay variables en inglés además?

Lo mejor es separar el problema en 2 funciones:

Suma de un array de números
Encontrar el máximo valor de un array

Hay muchas formas de implementar estas funciones, algunas más complejas que otras. En este caso intentaré usar algoritmos simples
1.- Suma de un array de números
El algoritmo es bastante simple, recorres el array y vas sumando cada elemento. En tu código yo aprecio que esto lo entiendes ya que tienes algo similar


Array.prototype.Sum = function(){
  let result = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    result += this[i];
  }
  return result;
}

let array_test = [7965,8714,8446,2612,7241,2872,2008,4857,4896,4986,5746,6676,5285,4427,5843,8285,8601,5245,7582,9616,3245,9253,6749,2109,9709,6883,4239,3458,1215,9451,3573,7977,5037,7242,7380,3856,3444,5911,5452,9878,5781,2218,7557,5580,6199,6821,2204,2305,8746,7637,8682,4409,4749];

console.log( array_test.Sum() )



La diferencia es que yo he decido usar Array.prototype.Sum = function() de esta manera le agrego la función a los array y me permite llamarla de esta manera:
array.Sum();

En caso contrario habría que llamarla de forma "normal" como:
Sum(array)

Esto lo hago solo por legibilidad (es un gusto personal)
2.- Encontrar el valor máximo
El algoritmo es muy similar, recorres el array (pero en lugar de sumar) te quedar con el valor máximo


Array.prototype.Max = function(fn){
   let max_value = Number.MIN_VALUE;
   let result = null;
   
   for(let i=0; i < this.length; i++){
      let x = fn( this[i] );
      if ( x > max_value ){
          max_value = x;
          result = this[i];
      }
   }
   return result;
}

let test_array = [7965,8714,8446,2612,7241,2872,2008,4857,4896,4986,5746,6676,5285,4427,5843,8285,8601,5245,7582,9616,3245,9253,6749,2109,9709,6883,4239,3458,1215,9451,3573,7977,5037,7242,7380,3856,3444,5911,5452,9878,5781,2218,7557,5580,6199,6821,2204,2305,8746,7637,8682,4409,4749];

console.log( test_array.Max(a=>a) )



3.- Juntamos todo


// Funciones Utilitarias
Array.prototype.Sum = function() {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    result += this[i];
  }
  return result;
}

Array.prototype.Max = function(fn) {
  let max_value = Number.MIN_VALUE;
  let result = null;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    let x = fn(this[i]);
    if (x > max_value) {
      max_value = x;
      result = this[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
// =============================================


let comer = [ {nom:"Daniel",fact:[6899,2713,6827,5805,3058,3679,4094,7581,5867,6901,5116,2392]}, {nom:"Raquel",fact:[6747,5485,7431,2667,2431,3900,7222,7601,5109,6556,6211,7087]}, {nom:"Eva",fact:[2831,2645,2242,5586,3124,7396,5556,3268,3186,6632,5319,2263]}, {nom:"Víctor",fact:[4758,6212,7835,6240,6513,6639,4246,3244,5914,3338,2415,5240]}];


const mejor_comercial = comer.Max(a=> a.fact.Sum());
console.log("El comercial que vende mas es:", mejor_comercial.nom);

// Otras consultas que se pueden hacer

//mostrar cuando vende cada uno:
let comer_ext = comer.map( a=> ({...a, suma : a.fact.Sum() }))
console.log("Comerciales con la suma de sus ventas: ");
console.log(comer_ext);


//ordenar de menor a mayor ventas
let comer_ord = comer_ext.toSorted( (a,b) => a.suma - b.suma );
console.log("Comerciales ordenados por ventas: ");
console.log(comer_ord);


//como podras darte cuenta, ordenar por la suma es otra manera de encontrar el máximo o el minimo. Por ejemplo:

console.log("El que vende menos es ", comer_ord[0].nom );
console.log("El que vende más es ", comer_ord.at(-1).nom );




Más allá de la excelente respuesta de Yussef, quiero remarcar la fuente de
los problemas de tu código, imagina como funcionaría el siguiente código en
la vida real:
let nombreDeMaría = AzucenaDimeTuNombre();

Si, muy mal, bueno es lo que tiene tu código, problemas de nombres, porque el código en sí, está bien, hace lo que debe, repasemos el mismo:
La llamada a la función:
console.log( sumarIngresos( comer )));

además del hecho de que sobra un ")" (seguramente en el original no está así), nombras a la función comercial y la llamas como sumarIngresos (tampoco creo que esté así en el original), pero bueno, lo tengo que mencionar porque es lo que publicaste.
Ahora la linea que arroja el error:
for( let comercial of objeto ) {

el sistema te dice que objeto no está definido... y no lo está, mira tu función y no verás la declaración de la variable, o si?, en realidad la variable está declarada... pero con otro nombre, es el parámetro que recibe la función, si cambias objeto por tIngr, de repente tu función imprime la facturación de cada mercenario... digo comercial ;)


let comer = [     
    {nom:"Daniel",fact:[6899,2713,6827,5805,3058,3679,4094,7581,5867,6901,5116,2392]}, 
    {nom:"Raquel",fact:[6747,5485,7431,2667,2431,3900,7222,7601,5109,6556,6211,7087]}, 
    {nom:"Eva",fact:[2831,2645,2242,5586,3124,7396,5556,3268,3186,6632,5319,2263]},
    {nom:"Víctor",fact:[4758,6212,7835,6240,6513,6639,4246,3244,5914,3338,2415,5240]},     
];

function sumarIngresos( tIngr ) {     
    let arrayWithTotals = [];
    for( let comercial of tIngr ) {
        let subtotal = 0;
        for( let fact of comercial.fact ) {
           subtotal += parseInt( fact );
        }
        arrayWithTotals.push( 
            {nom: comercial.nom, total: subtotal}
        );
    }
    return arrayWithTotals;
}
console.log( sumarIngresos( comer ));



